# Domain of the derivative of the function $y=e^{\sec^2x}+3\cos^{-1}x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> Domain of $y'$ if $y=e^{\sec^2x}+3\cos^{-1}x$

It is said that the derivative of the given function is valid in $[-1,1]-\{0\}$.

$$
y'=e^{\sec^2x}\cdot2\sec x\cdot\sec x\tan x-\frac{3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=2\sec^2x\cdot\tan x\cdot e^{\sec^2x}-\frac{3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
$$
1-x^2>0\implies x^2<1\implies|x|<1\implies -1<x<1\implies x\in(-1,1)
$$
Both $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ are defined for $x=0$. Then how can it be $[-1,1]-\{0\}$ ?

Comment: @saulspatz in my reference it is said that the derivative is valid in $[-1,1]-\{0\}$ and the function itself is not defined at 0. but i dont see how that is true.

Comment: Yes, I was asking what is your reference.  I agree with all your comments in the question.

Comment: For $x=0$ we get $-3$ in the first derivative.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thanx. but i dont get ur point ?

Comment: @saulspatz pls check it for the exact wording in my reference, https://ibb.co/fGnEAS

Comment: It's a clear error; the function is certainly defined at $0$ and also differentiable.

Comment: @egreg ok thanx. could u pls confirm u mean the function is defined for $[-1,1]$ and its derivative in $(-1,1)$ ?

Answer (score -1):

ok the first derivative is given by $$f'(x)=2\, \left( \sec \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}\tan \left( x \right) {
{\rm e}^{ \left( \sec \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}-3\,{\frac {1}{
\sqrt {-{x}^{2}+1}}}
$$
from the term with the square root we get $$(1-x)(1+x)>0$$
and $$\cos(x)\ne 0$$

Comment: thanks but pls check my question. i am asking where all its derivative is defined.

Comment: could u pls confirm the derivative is defined for $x\in(-1,1)$, hence what is given in my reference is wrong ?

Comment: why is it required that  $\cos x \neq 0$?

Comment: @CSquared because the secant function has poles whenever the cosine is $0$. I suspect that was the source of the mistake in the book; they may have read "$\csc$" instead, which *is* undefined at $0$